# Transfer iOS app data to a different account

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id

I have an iPad 2 currently using my AppleID. I want to reset it
(almost) completely and change it to my girlfriend's Apple ID.

**The thing is:** there are 2 or 3 apps whose data we really don't want to
loose. They are free apps, so it's trivial to reinstall them under the
new account.

I only need a way of backing up the data of these apps **under *my* Apple
ID** and then restoring it **under *her* Apple ID**.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm not trying to transfer purchases or anything like that, just copy
some data.

*NOTE:* The software needs to be Windows or Linux.

Comment: Could you specify if this is app data that is manageable via the iTunes "On this Device" manager? Examples of this include the Kindle app and things of that nature where content can be loaded or unloaded from the device.

Comment: They are saved game data. They are not manageable via iTunes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can backup data from apps with a program such as [PhoneView](https://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) (Mac) or [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) (Mac & Windows).

> Browse, manage and download most any data saved by App Store apps from your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch. If you're looking for a quick way to download saved recordings, videos or images from your apps, this is it. Even transfer game high scores between devices. *--PhoneView*

This data can then be restored to a new installation of an app under a different Apple ID or even on a different device.

Comment: Forgot to say: it needs to run on Windows or Linux. I don't have access to any Mac machine. =/ Sorry about that.

Comment: @BruceConnor Added [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) which is both Mac & Windows :)

Answer (score 2):

Extending [@grgarside's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91357/44901):

1. Acquire [iTools](http://www.pocketmeta.com/itools-guide-troubleshooting-file-management-ios-devices-2372/), [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/), and a Windows or Mac desktop computer
2. Use iTools to backup the apps to desktop
3. Uninstall all apps
4. change AppleID for App store, iCloud, etc. everywhere on device
5. Power off/on cycle
6. Reinstall the apps from App store (not from backup!)
7. On desktop computer, unzip the `.ipa` files to a staging area
8. With iFunbox, for each application:

   - *Manage Files* and
   - copy `Documents` and `Library` from `{desktop}\staging_area\{app name}\Container\` to `{i-thing]\User Applications\{app name}\` ...and you should be good to go.

[image: screenshot of drag-n-drop from desktop file system to iFunbox user app folder]

*Notes:*

Strictly speaking, you should be able to use iFunbox for everything. However it crashed frequently on my Win7 system so I'm not inclined to use it more than necessary.

`.ipa` files are just zip archives with a different extension. You may need to rename `.zip` in order to extract the contents.

The reason for #3 and #6 is that the appleid is welded into the app before it is downloaded and installed. For the same reason we don't use either management app's native restore mechanism.

If the device is jailbroken you might be able to use iTools for the whole process. (On the unbroken ipad I was using the iTools file system view did not show the User Application data.)

This recipe worked for the half dozen apps I needed to move, but I expect some apps have a more complicated process, e.g. copy *X,Y,Z* from Documents, but leave behind *T,U,V* and edit the headers in *W,X* to the new account into.