# Is it still possible to migrate iphone app data to a new account by extracting the .ipa file and extracting the content?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, backup, user-account

For various reasons beyond the scope of this post, I must create a new Apple ID and iTunes account. There are a few apps on my phone that I must preserve the content from (I don't mind re-buying the app).

[This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91291/transfer-ios-app-data-to-a-different-account/153270) from 2013 indicated that I could backup the app .ipa file to my computer, retrieve the 'container' folder, and then restore it to the filesystem once installing the app under my new account.

However, the desktop applications used in that post don't seem to function properly with ios11 and I'm unable to access the filesystem to restore content.

- Is there another clever way to do this?
- If I switch accounts and try to re-install the app, will it locate the old data?

Comment: Can you just clarify what you mean by *If I switch accounts and try to re-install the app*? More specifically, do you mean switching to your new account and temporarily back to your old account? Also, how would you re-install the apps if they don't run on iOS 11?

Comment: @Monomeeth I would like to install the app I'd like to keep under <bad account>, sign out of <bad account> and sign in with <good account>, purchase the app that I'd like it to use, and have it locate my user data automatically. Re: app not working, I meant that the desktop application referenced in the post I linked does not support ios11.